Material UI React JS Select component with multiple value unable to deselect when more than 1 item is selected
So i am trying to implement a multiselect dropdown in material ui with the following conditions
The dropdown will have [0 Apples, 1 Oranges, 2 Grapes]
By default 0 Apples should be selected
None of the options can be unselected.
If 0 Apples is selected and the user selects 1 Oranges or 2 Grapes then 0 Apples will be unselected and either 1 Orange or 2 Grapes will be selected depending on what he selected.
If 1 Oranges is selected then 0 Apples will get unselected.
If 2 Grapes Is selected then 0 Apples will get unselected.
If 1 Oranges is selected 2 Grapes is selected then both of them will get selected.
If 2 Grapes is selected 1 Oranges is selected then both the will get selected.
I am having problems trying to implement the unselect logic for the following cases:
1 Oranges and 2 Grapes is selected then unselect either of them.
And i am not sure where it is not working. The variable actualNewSelectionByUser is empty because he is unselecting so i will read from actualSelected as in value of mui input. I will use this to delete the value in state. But this is not working.
Here is the code sandbox link
link to code sandbox

So I figured this out, working on the shortcoming of Shanka's answer I implemented the following:
Handles the case of length being 0 and if the last selected item is 0.
  const handleChange = (incomingValues) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = incomingValues;
    let newValues;
    if (value?.length === 0 || value[value?.length - 1] == 0) {
      newValues = [0];
    } else if (value?.includes(1) || value?.includes(2)) {
      newValues = value.filter((item) => item !== 0);
    } else {
      newValues = values;
    }
    setValues(newValues)
  }

The last selected item in the multiple Select component will be the last item in the array.
